# How to match all elements and get their contents in a page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, casperjs

I have a page like this:

```
<ul id="a">
  <li class="b">
    <a>Content1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="b">
    <a>Content2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="b">
    <a>Content3</a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I tried several ways, but I don't find the solution for get an array all the contents what I need.

With my example, I would like get:

```
array[0] = Content0

array[1] = Content1

array[2] = Content2
```

I tried: `casper.getHTML`, but its return the first element matched, I didn't understand why? Here with my example: `this.getHTML("ul#a li.b a")` returns only `"Content 1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use functions which return results for multiple elements. `getHTML` returns a string, so it returns only one result. One example is the [`getElementsInfo`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) function. Note the s in elements. It exposes the `text` property which you can use to get the expected array:

```
var array = casper.getElementsInfo("ul#a li.b a").map(function(a){
    return a.text;
});
```

If you don't find such a function then you could've made the same in the page context:

```
var array = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("ul#a li.b a"), function(a){
        return a.innerHTML;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx =) the casper.evaluate return null, but the casper.getElementsInfo works. I valid your answer but can you tell me why the evaluate return null ? (I used the same selector). I ask because before I tried several ways with the evaluate function but I haven't been able to do.

Comment: I changed from `innerText` to `innerHTML`